# meteor.js & mongodb - how to pass _id of current element in spacebars each

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, meteor

**CONTEXT**

I'm trying to update an object in Venue collection to contain the _id of an object in Event collection. The current page displays one Event, so `this.params._id` yields the _id of the current Event... I can manipulate that object.

**WHAT I NEED**

I'm using Spacebars' `each` to loop through venues on the front end. Next to each Venue item is an "Add Venue to Event" button - I would like this button to add the _id of the corresponding Venue to the Event displayed on the current page.

**PROBLEM**

`this` refers to the Event on the current page, *not* the venue currently being looped through in Spacebars. I'm not sure how to pass the _id of the venue in the current stage of `each` so that I can add it to event being displayed on current page.

**HELPER CODE**

```
//ADD SUGGESTED VENUE TO EVENT
  'click .suggest-venue': function(event) {
    var currentEventId = this.params._id;

    Meteor.call("updateEvent", currentEventId, {suggestedVenues: [Venues._id]})

    toastr.success("Venue Suggestion Added");
  }
```

This code yields `suggestedVenues: null` when you console.log the relevant Venue.

Comment: Can we see your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (solved by rglover on TheMeteorChef Slack Channel) was that because I'm using the [Differential Boiler Plate](https://github.com/Differential/meteor-boilerplate/blob/master/both/controllers/dashboard.js) for Meteor, the design patterns led me to put template helpers within the template's controller. This meant that `this` was referring to the route instance.

**SOLUTION**

I moved the event handler to the js file accompanying each template, therefore `this` now refers to the template data, allowing me to get the `_id` of the element being clicked. As for the `_id` of the Event displayed on the page, `Router.current().params._id` allowed me to access it.

Hope this helps anyone else who may have gone down this path!

Answer (score 1):

As you've identified, you need to pass two key pieces of data into your method: the Event ID and the Venue ID.

The [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) say this about event handlers:

> The handler also receives some additional context data in `this`, depending on the context of the current element handling the event. In a template, an element's context is the data context where that element occurs, which is set by block helpers such as `#with` and `#each`.

So, your event handler should look something like this:

```js
'click .suggest-venue': function() {
    var eventId = Router.current().params._id; // Assuming you're using iron:router
    var venueId = this._id; // 'this' is the current context within your template at the target element of this event handler       

    Meteor.call('updateEvent', eventId, venueId);
}
```

I'll leave the method itself as an exercise for the reader ;)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - you were correct, though I had to make other changes as well (see my answer).